# Loop and fetch values from Json script using Python

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-vpc

I have a JSON script in which I need to fetch out series of values using loops in Python. Sample Json snippet is shown below,

```
{
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RetryAttempts': 0,
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'RequestId': 'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'date': 'Tue, 19 Nov 2019 12:40:10 GMT',
            'vary': 'accept-encoding',
            'content-length': '2236',
            'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
            'server': 'AmazonEC2'
        }
    },
    u 'RouteTables': [{
        u 'Associations': [{
            u 'SubnetId': 'subnet-aaaaaa',
            u 'RouteTableAssociationId': 'rtvvvvvvv-24234234234234',
            u 'Main': False,
            u 'RouteTableId': 'rtb-32423423'
        }, {
            u 'RouteTableAssociationId': 'rtbassoc-ebec234324',
            u 'Main': True,
            u 'RouteTableId': 'rtb-324234234'
        }],
        u 'RouteTableId': 'rtb-234234',
        u 'VpcId': 'vpc-2342342',
        u 'PropagatingVgws': [],
        u 'Tags': [],
        u 'Routes': [{
            u 'GatewayId': 'local',
            u 'DestinationCidrBlock': '435.43.0.0/16',
            u 'State': 'active',
            u 'Origin': 'CreateRouteTable'
        }, {
            u 'GatewayId': 'igw-a234234',
            u 'DestinationCidrBlock': '0.0.0.0/0',
            u 'State': 'active',
            u 'Origin': 'CreateRoute'
        }, {
            u 'GatewayId': 'vpce-234234',
            u 'Origin': 'CreateRoute',
            u 'State': 'active',
            u 'DestinationPrefixListId': 'pl-234234'
        }, {
            u 'GatewayId': 'vpce-sadasdsaddds4',
            u 'Origin': 'CreateRoute',
            u 'State': 'active',
            u 'DestinationPrefixListId': 'pl-2342344'
        }]
    }]
}
```

In the above json, I need to fetch 'DestinationPrefixListId'. As I am new to Python loop concept using boto3 (SDK for aws and python) library, not able to fetch the list. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you gone through https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json ?

Comment: consider using json.loads, this will get converted to a python dictionary, post which you can access the fields like you do with a regular dict.

Comment: the above is not JSON. JSON uses double quotes

Comment: The output in this question is just a dump of a Python dictionary. This question is really just "how do I loop in Python" and doesn't have anything to do with JSON.

Comment: The value you have is an unicode dictionary , convert it first into a dictionary using ``eval(json.dumps(c))``` , then you can simply loop using key, value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and help. I have formed a for loop and got the required output. Please find the below code,

```
r = data['RouteTables'][0]['Routes']
for x in r:
   a = x 
   if 'DestinationPrefixListId' in r[x]:
      b =  a.get('DestinationPrefixListId')
```

"data" denotes the above Json posted. Using the above code, I am able to get the values that are required. Thank you all. Have a good day!!

Comment: actually you don't need `a = x` assignment

Comment: In order to get the value of 'DestinationPrefixListId'. I have used "a = x". The data type of obtained output is String which I have used for the further data manipulation.

Comment: your code will only work if there is one element in `RouteTables` and also you can make it look better if you write `x.get('DestinationPrefixListId')` instead of `a = x`. And more, in that case you will have to append the value of `b` to a list which is also has worse perfomance than `list comprehensions`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your task correct:

```
[y.get("DestinationPrefixListId") for x in data["RouteTables"] for y in x["Routes"] if y.get("DestinationPrefixListId")]
```

Will return:

```
['pl-234234', 'pl-2342344']
```

Comment: RouteTables is a list. Its indice must be an integer. So, `["RouteTables"]['Routes'] ` cannot be mentioned together.

Comment: @Avinash my bad, the indentation is not that great